# using fetch in refactored code

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

I've been able to wrap my head around the `Promise` of `fetch` when I'm writing in one file, but once I start splitting code into multiple files I get stuck. This has happened a couple times, and I must be missing or transposing some concept.

This is in the context of node.js.

I've put my Promise code in a separate file:

```
module.exports = function(url, branch) {
  return fetch(url)
  .then( res => res.json())
  // here's the meat and potatoes.
  .then( data => data => Object.keys(data.values).filter( value => value.source.branch === branch))
  .catch( err => console.log(err))
};
```

Then in the file that I'm using this function:

```
const getDescription = require('./get_description');
getDescription(url, branch )
// This is where I want to use this value.
  .then( desc => console.log(desc) )
  .catch( err => console.log(err) );
```

And, it just spits out `[Function]`.

When I lump it all together I seem to be able to get what I need, but I'm also doing something weird with how I'm nesting the `res.json().then` inside the other.

```
fetch(`https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/${circle_project_username}/${circle_project_reponame}/pullrequests`, {headers: {Authorization: auth}})
  .then((res) => {
    res.json().then((data) => {
      Object.keys(data.values).forEach(key => {
        if (data.values[key].source.branch.name === branch) {
          console.log(data.values[key].description);
        }
      })
    })
  })
 .catch(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: Remove these `.catch(err => console.log(err) );`s from everywhere - you are just making confusing flows by handling those errors without actually handling them!

Comment: You have a typo `.then( res => res.json)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning function `res.json` instead of `res.json()` promise

Replace

```
.then( res => res.json)
```

with

```
.then( res => res.json())
```

Also

Repalce

```
.then( data => data => Object.keys(data.values).filter( value => value.source.branch === branch))
```

with

```
 .then( data => Object.keys(data.values).filter( value => value.source.branch === branch))
```

Comment: Nice catch, but that doesn't change the outcome

Comment: @icicleking Update my answer. I think there is another mistake in your code, you are returning function not the filtered aarray/data